# How do I know when redux mapStateToProps values are connected and initialised in a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So I am happily using React with the connect() HOC and mapStateToProps and it works superbly. However, it seems that near the beginning of a component's lifecycle the Redux-connected props are not initialised. Is there a specific point in the component lifecycle where mapStateToProps-based props can be considered initialised and equal to the values in the store?

Comment: What's your initial state in store?

Answer (score 0):

All props are initialized and available everywhere in component

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give some default value then use `defaultProps`.

According to the flow of redux, when a action is dispatched, it goes to `reducer` changes the `store`, component with `connect` function is subscribed to `state` defined in `mapStateToProps`. So when value in corresponding state changes in store that props will be initialized or provided with that value.

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay mapStateToProps-based props are available as any other props are available in your Component. The thing is when you return a new state from the reducer all of the mapStateToProps gets called again and return the updated state from redux store,
So your initial state is available as any other props.
You can check your componentDidMount() will have initial state.

And as connect is a HOC so your component mounts after the HOC is been called and return your Component

Hope it helps